# packageName not found gradle build AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android

Up until this point, I have been able to build my gradle file just fine. But when I try to upload my apk to the play store it says the packageName cannot be found when i have it defined in my manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.aaronapp.hideme">

        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
            </provider>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is a screenshot of the project folder and how it looks:

[image]

Finally, here is my app level gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaronapp.hideme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the reason that it is not finding my packageName?

Comment: Shouldn't your manifest have `com.aaronapp.hideme` instead of `com.aaronapp.android`?

Comment: that is strange that it is not com.aaronapp.hideme in the code snippet because in my Android Studio it is com.aaronapp.hideme

Comment: Well, it was `com.aaronapp.android` when you copied and pasted it here so...

Comment: Yes i'll change that right now because that is not the case in my program

Comment: Also, your project structure doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: the project structure is also not right because gradle hasn't built it and it hasn't been indexed

Comment: And I'm afraid it wont since you have a new project folder inside your `app` folder. I think gradle will need to read your manifest file from the root of `app` folder.

Comment: so how would I got about re indexing everything and building it? Do you know where this problem could be stemming from?

Comment: I think you just have to copy the contents of your `sampledata` folder and place them inside `app`. Remove the `sampledata` afterwards.

Comment: alright i will try that

Comment: thank you Pedro! That solved my issue, you should have put that as an answer to get some rep ;)

Comment: For the sake of visibility, I've added the solution as answer  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help anyone with this problem:

The current project structure is incorrect. Gradle is expecting a `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside the `app/src/main` folder. For that reason, you should copy the contents of your `sampledata` folder, place them in the root of `app` and remove the `sampledata` folder. 
This way, gradle will be able read the package from the `AndroidManifest.xml`